# Getting empty rows of GROUP BY Date without joining to a dummy date table

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, group-by

I have the following SQL table (I am using **PostgreSQL**)

```
create table roombooking (
    r_no integer references room,
    b_ref integer references booking,
    checkin date not null,
    checkout date not null,
    primary key (r_no, b_ref)
);
```

**where** b_ref denotes a unique booking number per customer who checks in
.
I would like to get number of checkins per day so I use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(b_ref)
FROM roombooking
GROUP BY (checkin)
```

This query is part of a for loop in a Java program which increments the date by one day and adds the results of the query to an ArrayList.

**The problem is**: Some dates have no customers checking in (b_refs on this particular day) so SQL unfortunately completely skips those rows instead of returning 0. This is a huge problem for my Java program because the length of the ArrayList varies depending on the dates I loop through.

**A possible solution** would be to create a **dummy** table of dates and then joining it to my table. But I want to avoid this.

**Is there a possibility** to get SQL to simply return 0 for those dates **WITHOUT**  creating a dummy table of dates and joining them together.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need dummy table. Try this `select cast(mydate as date) from generate_series('2016-12-01','2016-12-10',interval'1day') as t(mydate)`

You can have it as joined part of your query and this way you can set start and end day as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

```
with days as (select generate_series('2016-12-01','2016-12-13','1 day'::interval)) 
SELECT COUNT(b_ref)
JOIN days on generate_series = checkin 
FROM roombooking
GROUP BY (checkin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can *generate* that "dummy table" on the fly:

```
SELECT dt.checkdate::date, COUNT(r.b_ref)
FROM generate_series(date '2016-01-01', date '2016-12-31', interval '1' day) as dt (checkdate)
  LEFT JOIN roombooking r ON r.checkin = dt.checkdate::date
GROUP BY dt.checkdate::date
```

Of course you need to adjust the start and end date for the interval you want to check.